# Where to initialize ObjectFactory in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I need to initialize `StructureMap.ObjectFactory` in ASP.NET MVC 3 application.

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.For<Db>().HttpContextScoped().Use<Db>());
```

Do I have to do it in `Application_BeginRequest` or `Application_Start`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule, you should always setup your IoC container in the `Application_Start` event handler, since it only needs to happen *once* during the lifetime of the application.

In the case of StructureMap, [the documentation recommends](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/ConfiguringStructureMap.htm#section5) to separate the [container configuration code](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/ConfiguringStructureMap.htm) in a separate `Bootstrapper` class:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Bootstrap()
    {
        // ObjectFactory.Initialize(...
    }
}
```

which you then invoke from the `Application_Start` event handler:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Bootstrapper.Bootstrap();
}
```